# Export CSV with Dynamic Values Based on MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have the following code snippet that works great except that portion of the file export are hard-coded.  I've gotten this close but have not idea how to achieve the following::

1. Omit the PictureCount field from displaying as a column in the
   export
2. Instead of hardcoding _1.jpg, I need to use the PictureCount value to generate a fresh record based on this count for each record (example: .$jpg_name."_.$Picture_Count.jpg

This is the code I do have working:

```
$values = mysql_query("SELECT PictureCount, ListingRid AS Home_ID FROM ".$table." WHERE (COUNTY='ACME' OR COUNTY="TEST")");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values)) 
{
  if ($row == 0)
  $row++;

      $csv_output .= "company_id|";
  foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
  {
      if($name=='Home_ID') {$jpg_name=$value;}
      $csv_output .= $value."|";
  }
  {
      $csv_output .= "http://www.acmerealestate.com/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_1.jpg ";
  }    
      $csv_output .= "\n";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to change columns in SQL. First you need to add `Home_ID` and then `PicCount`

All images in list you can just loop from 1 to `PictureCount` and just add images to list.

```
<?php
$values = mysql_query("SELECT ListingRid AS Home_ID, PictureCount FROM ".$table." WHERE (COUNTY='ACME' OR COUNTY="TEST")");
$row = 0;
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_assoc($values))
{
    if ($row == 0)
        $row++;

    $csv_output .= "company_id|";
    foreach($rowr as $name => $value)
    {
        if($name=='Home_ID') {$jpg_name=$value;}
        $csv_output .= $value."|";
        if ($name == 'PictureCount') {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $value; $i ++)
            $csv_output .="http://www.acmerealestate.com/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/".$jpg_name."_".$i.".jpg|";
        }
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}
```